# What is difference in web-component app-layout 2.0.0 and app-layout 2.0.4

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I have not idea about difference in web-component `app-layout 2.0.0` and  `app-layout 2.0.4`.

I have build one PWA that use all component with `version 2.0.0` in bower.

My query is

- Should i update all bower dependency,
- Will my PWA performance going to increase after updating

*below is version number screenshot.*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I have not idea about difference in web-component app-layout 2.0.0 and  app-layout 2.0.4.

These are the [relevant commits between v2.0.0 and v2.0.4](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout/compare/v2.0.0...v2.0.4):

```
2dd9d82 Use different promise polyfill to avoid dep on Polymer 1
17d1d4c Added printer-friendly media queries to app-header-layout and app-drawer-layout
4a1fccc fixes #484
63d5436 Avoid style recalc by reordering operations
2959a53 Wait until attached before setting initial state
a355015 Changed the media query strategy regarding print and has-scrolling-region on app-header-layout
58d536e ensure to multiply by a number
17f1296 (origin/closure) ensure to pass number to cancelAnimationFrame
```

There might be one performance improvement in `63d5436`.

> Should i update all bower dependency,

That depends on whether the commits above provide any advantage to you.

> Will my PWA performance going to increase after updating

Given the change in `63d5436`, which avoids a style recalculation, you may see a rendering performance improvement (i.e., reduced jank, if any) while dragging the `app-drawer`.